# Can VToolBox run background on IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, h.264, hardware-acceleration

I want to compress some data with VToolBox. When I run my app in the foreground it runs well, but when I run my app in the background it gives no compressed data anymore...

I added logs when the encoding starts:

```
- (void) encode1:(CMSampleBufferRef )sampleBuffer  wrapTs:(UInt64)ts;
{
    dispatch_sync(aQueue, ^{

    frameCount++;
    // Get the CV Image buffer
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    // Create properties
    CMTime presentationTimeStamp = CMTimeMake(frameCount, 1000);
    //CMTime duration = CMTimeMake(1, DURATION);
    VTEncodeInfoFlags flags;

    //NSLog(@"encode sessino status:%d", EncodingSession==nil? 0:1);
    // Pass it to the encoder
    OSStatus statusCode = VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame(EncodingSession,
                                                          imageBuffer,
                                                          presentationTimeStamp,
                                                          kCMTimeInvalid,
                                                          NULL, (__bridge void*)@(ts), &flags);

    NSLog(@"hardware compress result: %d", (int)statusCode);
    // Check for error
    if (statusCode != noErr) {
```

and in the compress callback:

```
void didCompressH264(void *outputCallbackRefCon, void *sourceFrameRefCon, OSStatus status, VTEncodeInfoFlags infoFlags,
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer ){
   //get outside stamp
   UInt64 pp = [((__bridge NSNumber*)sourceFrameRefCon) longLongValue];

   NSLog(@"didCompressH264 status:%d", status);
   if (status != 0) return;

   if (!CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer))
   {
      NSLog(@"didCompressH264 data is not ready ");
      return;
   }
```

When I run the app in the background, I can see the log "hardware compress result: 0" which means put data into VToolBox well, but I can't get log "didCompressH264 status".

It seems it never reaches the `didCompressH264` function.

So, I wonder if VToolBox can run in the background? If so, how? Any answer is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

iOS won't let you app run in the background forever. By default, it will give you just a few seconds of running time after the app moves to the background. Beyond that, it will either prevent the app from running or kill it.

You can ask for more time using `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:` in your AppDelegate's `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method. You can check with `backgroundTimeRemaining` how long iOS gives you. Beyond that, your app will be killed.

Note that quite a few things don't work the same in the background. Not sure what resources the library uses, but I would be surprised if you got full access to the GPU while in the background, for instance.

Comment: By setting "Required background modes" or the way you advised, we are sure that the app is running on background.  The log "hardware compress result: 0" is also keep printing all the time. The problem is even we can put data into VToolBox, but we cann't get compressed data from it.

Answer (score 0):

VideoToolbox stops decompressing frames as soon as your app enters background. Hardware acceleration is only permitted on the foreground application to provide the best experience.